# Twilio GET requests are breaking my server

Tags: twilio

Here's my "hello world" static XML endpoint:
http://catface.biz/twilio/webhook/

When I call my Twilio number, and Twilio requests that page, I get the "An application error has occurred" voice on the line.

Using the Twilio debugger, I can see that my server isn't responding with XML. Instead, it's responding with "Connection to Tomcat has been closed," which is causing Twilio to report a 12100 error.

Of course the error is on my end. But my question remains: what the heck is Twilio sending that's breaking my server?

The XML on my end is static. It should be responding with "Hello World", as it does when you visit my endpoint in your browser.

If you have a Twilio account, add this URL as your endpoint and then give it a call. You'll see the error:
http://catface.biz/twilio/webhook/

Any ideas?

Comment: I just made two calls to that webhook as a Twilio call and it reacted as expected. Are you still seeing the same error?

Comment: @philnash Still getting the same error. Try calling 214-390-9332 and you'll hear "We're sorry..." Here's are screenshots of the [configuration](http://i.imgur.com/3fPadmu.png) and [error log](http://i.imgur.com/5leZx9A.png). Did you make your calls to the webhook by really setting it up in Twilio.com? Or did you just simulate it?

Comment: @PhilipKaplan I set up a webhook pointing to http://catface.biz/twilio/webhook/ on my Twilio number, called it, and it worked just fine for me too (via both GET and POST).
When I called your number I got the error you describe. Strange. Could you post a shot of the console with the Request expanded? Have you checked the error logs on your server?

Comment: can you copy paste the exact code for the endpoint "http://catface.biz/twilio/webhook/' ?

Comment: I did set up a webhook with my Twilio account and it worked for me. As am1704 asks, can we see the code? What do your web server logs show when getting connections from your Twilio number?

Comment: @philnash Looks like Twilio Support fixed it by upgrading the API version from 2008-08-01 to 2010-04-01 for that number. Now I need to upgrade my other Twilio phone numbers, but I can't find a way to do it other than emailing Twilio support. Also, odd that my numbers would be on an old API version, since they are brand new numbers I setup via Twilio website. Any idea how I can upgrade other Twilio numbers I have, to the latest API version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio customer support (yay!) figured out the problem.

Apparently, the phone number was setup in Twilio's system to use an old Twilio API. And that API was somehow breaking my system.

It's odd to me that the number was using an old API, considering I acquired the phone number from Twilio within the past few weeks.

Regardless, if anyone else reading this is experiencing problems, email support@twilio.com and ask them to upgrade your phone number's API version from "2008-08-01" to "2010-04-01". Yes, it's 2016 as I write this.